# resolve Makefile wildcard % inside shell function

Tags: shell, makefile, wildcard

it seems that make doesn't resolve the wildcard character % before calling the shell function, in cases like this one:

```
%.exe: $(shell cat %.txt)
    gcc $? -o $@
```

if I type this on the shell:

```
$ make test.exe
```

the shell complains that it cannot find "%.txt," but I was expecting it to find "test.txt".

is there anyway to workaround that?

thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify on what you are trying to accomplish with this rule?

Comment: for every executable X, there's a file X.txt listing all its source dependencies. I want 'make' to put the contents of that file as the target dependencies.

Comment: The expansion of $(shell ...) happens very early; your error happens before make even starts looking at targets. Please read the "secondary expansion" chapter in the documentation of GNU Make as suggested below.

Answer (score 3):

You can use secondary expansion feature of GNU make:

```
$ cat Makefile
all : x.exe
.PHONY: all
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%.exe: $$(shell cat $$(basename $$(@F)).txt)
    @echo "$@ depends on $^"

$ cat x.txt 
a
b
c

$ touch a b c

$ make
x.exe depends on a b c
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `foo.txt` contain the dependencies for `foo.exe` in `Makefile` format:

```
foo.exe: foo.o bar.o baz.o
```

Then use an `include` line in your `Makefile`:

```
include foo.txt
```

Lastly, update your pattern rule:

```
%.exe:
    gcc -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Honestly, I'd just use a generator like `automake`. It saves a lot of these headaches and the result is portable.

Comment: Portable by what metric? `automake`'s output works across just about any POSIX `make`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do this:

```
.SUFFIXES: .exe .txt
.txt.exe:
        gcc $? -o $@
```

Comment: No, he's not. The .txt file names all of the dependencies of the .exe file.

Comment: Ah! In that case, he should put the dependencies in the Makefile rather than the .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the usual way to load (dynamically generated) dependencies from an external file is to use *include*. I.e. you can fix your example, you can just add the destination(s) during your %.txt file generation. In the Makefile you can write then something like this:

```
DEPS = $(OBJS:.o=.txt)

-include $(DEPS)
```

BTW, the usually used suffix for these dependency file is %.d.

Following [web site shows an intelligent approach to integrate the dependency generation in your Makefile.](http://make.paulandlesley.org/autodep.html) I.e. the dependency files are then generated and updated as needed. No need for an 'make deps' step or something like that.